# Related to matrix equations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $p$ and $q$ be real numbers such that $x^2+px+q\ \not= \ 0 $ for all real x. Prove that if n is an odd positive integer , then $X^2+pX+qI_n\ \not= \ 0_n$ for real matrices $ X$ of order n×n.

I am not able to show my attempt because I don't have any idea where to start . Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Suppose $X^2+pX+qI =O$

Since $n$ is odd, it must have a real eigenvalue, multiply it with the corresponding eigenvector to obtain a contradiction. I wll leave the details to you.

Edit:

Since $n$ is odd, then the charactheristic equation, $\det(x I-X)=0$, which is an odd degree polynomial must have a real root, $\lambda$.

That is we can find a real number $\lambda$ such that $\det(\lambda I-X)=0$,

Hence if you consider the linear system, $(\lambda I-X)v=0$,  we must be able to find a non-zero vector $v$ that satisfies the equation. That is we must have such $v$ such that $Xv=\lambda v$.

Now, suppose that we have $X^2+pX+qI=O$, post multiply the equation by $v$ and try to simplify the system.

Comment: where does the question come from? any particular topic that you are studying?

Comment: I looked at your previous posts and realized that you have the concept of Cayley Hamilton, perhaps you might like to think along that line. It's very strange that you learn Cayley Hamilon without knowing about eigenvalues though.

Comment: Actually our sir told us to just accept it as a fact ,But how do i use cayley hamilton theorm for a general n order matrix when i have been given a quadratic equation.

Comment: I can't think of how to use that directly now, but I have tried to avoid using the term "eigen" and tried to explain assuming that you have the concept of determinant and non-trivial solution.

Comment: Can we say for a matrix equation be zero , the polynomial must have $\lambda$ as it's root ?

Comment: hmmm.... i can't understand your question. what matrix equation, which polynomial?

Comment: $\lambda$ is the real value for which det|$\lambda I - A|$ is zero, polynomial equation is  $x^2+px+q$ and the matrix equation is $A^2+pA+qI_n=0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104524/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-aryan-bansal).